# ¿Cómo corregir este Error de Compilación en VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo una macro para preguntar una lista de códigos de dientes de los pacientes con el fin de imprimirla en una celda junto a un texto, de igual forma una vez se imprime en la celda de la derecha imprime el precio según la cantidad de dientes dimite el usuario, lo cual funciona bien. Sin embargo, arroja el error:

> Error de compilación: El tipo no coincide

Ya que no se si se esta imprimiendo en la celda correctamente el texto junto a la variable definida como un vector

```
Sub DIENTES()

Dim numd As Integer
Dim tooth(1 To 50) As String
Dim ttooth As String
Set r = ActiveCell

numd = InputBox("¿DIGITE CUANTOS DIENTES A REMPLAZAR?")

For i = 1 To numd
 tooth(i) = InputBox("Digite el diente " & i)
Next i

ttooth = InputBox("BIODENT (B), DURATONE (D)")

Select Case ttooth
    Case "B"
        Dim bi As Variant
        bi = 20000
        r.Value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / BIODENT (c/u $20.000) en: " & tooth
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = bi * numd
    Case "D"
        Dim du As Variant
        du = 35000
        r.value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / DURATONE (c/u $35.000) en: " & tooth
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = du * numd
    Case Els
        MsgBox ("ERROR DE DIGITACION")
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
Sub DIENTES()

    Dim numd As Integer
    Dim tooth As String
    Dim ttooth As String
    Set r = ActiveCell
    
    numd = InputBox("¿DIGITE CUANTOS DIENTES A REMPLAZAR?")
    
    For i = 1 To numd
       tooth = InputBox("Digite el diente " & i)
       ttooth = InputBox("BIODENT (B), DURATONE (D)")
    
       Select Case ucase(ttooth)
           Case "B"
               Dim bi As Variant
               bi = 20000
               r.Value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / BIODENT (c/u $20.000) en: " & tooth
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = bi * numd
           Case "D"
               Dim du As Variant
               du = 35000
               r.Value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / DURATONE (c/u $35.000) en: " & tooth
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = du * numd
           Case Els
               MsgBox ("ERROR DE DIGITACION")
       End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el cambio?

Comment: El cambio está en la línea: "Dim tooth(1 To 50) As String" y en "tooth(i) = InputBox("Digite el diente " & i)". Lineas 4 y 11.

Comment: Pero entonces este código lo único que hará será guardar en `tooth` el último valor del bucle. ¿No debería estar todo dentro del for?

Comment: Cierto, me había centrado únicamente en el error y no me he parado a comprobar el funcionamiento completo. He editado el código, creo que te referías a dejarlo así.

Comment: Ahora tiene más sentido

Answer (score 1):

Te muestra el error `tipo no coincide` porque estas concatenando un `String` y un `ArrayString` en el `case B:` y `case D:`, para solucionarlo debes suministrar el indice al `String` que quieres hacer referencia, ejemplo `tooth(i)` pero esto requiere que el valor de la variable `i` sea dinámico, es decir debes incluir tu `Select case` dentro de un ciclo `for` de la misma manera como lo hiciste para llenar la variable `tooth`. Espero te sea de ayuda:

```
Sub DIENTES()


Dim numd As Integer
Dim tooth(1 To 50) As String
Dim ttooth As String
Set r = ActiveCell

numd = InputBox("¿DIGITE CUANTOS DIENTES A REMPLAZAR?")


For i = 1 To numd
    tooth(i) = InputBox("Digite el diente " & i)
    ttooth = InputBox("BIODENT (B), DURATONE (D)")
    Select Case ttooth
        Case "B"
            Dim bi As Variant
            bi = 20000
            r.Value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / BIODENT (c/u $20.000) en: " & tooth(i)
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = bi * numd
        Case "D"
            Dim du As Variant
            du = 35000
            r.Value = "-DIENTES A REEMPLAZAR / DURATONE (c/u $35.000) en: " & tooth(i)
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = du * numd
        Case Els
            MsgBox ("ERROR DE DIGITACION")
    End Select
Next i

End Sub
```